# TFS 2018 WebLayout extension forcing all contributions from extension to display

Tags: tfs

We are moving on-premises TFS2015 to TFS2018U1 and I am fighting with the new WebLayout definition.

We've got a few heavily customized work item types to track our larger projects, a custom work item type above the Epic level.  The state engine in these WITs is complex, so I'd like to show a diagram in the work item that shows the workflow.  Simply embedding a  with CDATA <img> didn't give me enough control to adjust the size of the  containing the image, so I've written a simple extension to give me more control over this display.  The content of the extension is working properly; my issue is with unexpected behavior in the work item WebLayout.

We have three project types, so my extension has three contributions in vss-extension.json (names have been changed):

```
"contributions": [
    {
        "id": "projects.type1.workflow-group",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-group",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Project Type 1 Workflow",
            "uri": "project-type-1-workflow-group.html",
            "height": 800
        }
    }, {
        "id": "projects.type2.workflow-group",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-group",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Project Type 2 Workflow",
            "uri": "project-type-2-workflow-group.html",
            "height": 800
        }        
    }, {
        "id": "projects.type3.workflow-group",
        "type": "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form-group",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-work-web.work-item-form"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Project Type 3 Workflow",
            "uri": "project-type-3-workflow-group.html",
            "height": 800
        }
    }
```

My three different work item type definitions then each call one of these extensions:

```
<WebLayout>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Id="MyAccount.web-layout" />
  </Extensions>
  <Page Label="Page1">
    ...
  </Page>
  <Page Label="Page2">
    ...
  </Page>
  <Page Label="Page3">
    <Section>
      ...
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <GroupContribution Id="MyAccount.web-layout.projects.project1.workflow-group" Label="Workflow" />
    </Section>
  </Page>
...
</WebLayout>
```

My problem is that the two unused extension contributions get injected into each work item type.  For instance, when I view the Project Type 1 work item, I see the Project Type 1 workflow / image where I want it to be, but the other two workflow / images are injected into the first page of the WebLayout, despite the work item type definition making no reference to them; they're not there when I import the work item type definition, they have magically appeared when I export them back out.

When I export the work item type definition back out of TFS, there are two GroupContribution tags injected into the second section of the first page (the first section is System.Description, which is also injected by TFS, which is a separate issue):

```
        <GroupContribution Label="Project Type 2 Workflow" Id="MyAccount.web-layout.projects.project2.workflow-group" />
        <GroupContribution Label="Project Type 3 Workflow" Id="MyAccount.web-layout.projects.project3.workflow-group" />
```

I would rather not build a separate extension for each GroupContribution I want to use; I could create a single GroupContribution that dynamically figures out which image to display, but if I want to start adding other GroupContribution (or PageContribution, etc.) content, I fear I'll run into the same issue.

How can I use an extension with multiple contributions, without having MS / TFS inject the unused ones into random parts of my Web Layout?

Comment: Did you customize your work item in old form first then upgrade to TFS 2018 and transfer to new form? Or  you are directly customizing  the new form work item?

Comment: The old work item didn't support <WebLayout>, so I've added it and imported it into our test 2018 instance.  The only difference between the 2015 and 2018 variants is the whole <WebLayout> section, and this new extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when a work item type definition references an extension, all contributions in that extension will appear in the WebLayout, regardless of whether they're explicitly used in the WebLayout definition or not.  However, you can explicitly reference the ones you don't want to see / use, and hide them:

```
<WebLayout>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Id="MyAccount.web-layout" />
  </Extensions>
  <Page Label="Page1">
    ...
  </Page>
  <Page Label="Page2">
    ...
  </Page>
  <Page Label="Page3">
    <Section>
      ...
    </Section>
    <Section>
      <GroupContribution Id="MyAccount.web-layout.projects.project1.workflow-group" Label="Workflow" />          
      <GroupContribution Id="MyAccount.web-layout.projects.project2.workflow-group" Label="Workflow" Visible="false" />         
      <GroupContribution Id="MyAccount.web-layout.projects.project3.workflow-group" Label="Workflow" Visible="false" />
    </Section>
  </Page>
...
</WebLayout>
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Or did you discover it by chance?

Comment: This was quite a while ago now, I think I just stumbled across the solution.  I don't really recall though.